# How to do a mass replace of a variable in NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans

How do I do a mass replace of a variable in a certain class in NetBeans IDE?

For example, I have `int myNumber = 2;` and I have `int mySecondNumber = 4;`.

If have `myNumber` spread out many places through my class. I want a way to be able to replace all of them with `mySecondNumber`.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a process called refactoring.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/Refactoring

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on any mention of `myNumber`, and click Refractor->Rename from the popup menu.

Alternatively, left-click on `myNumber` and use Ctrl-R.

Comment: Will this work for only one class, or does it change it to all classes in a package?

Comment: @ChristopherSpencer All classes where it is used.

Comment: That being said, make sure the changes have taken place in expected areas. Automated refactoring may accidentally miss, so it's better to be safe!